# Validate numbers in textbox using Jquery in MVC(Razor)

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(cModel => cModel.Value, new { id = "txtbLimit", @type = "int" })
```

And I want to make sure that what the user puts in there is an integer.

How can I do that?

EDIT: I dont parse this textBox with a value of a Model, so model validation is not what I want

EDIT2:

#### Model:

```
public class StorageConfigurationModel
{
    [Required]
    public int QueueMonitorConfigurationsID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public PathType QueueMonitorConfigTypeName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Location { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public UnitType QueueMonitorValueTypeName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public ThresholdType Threshold { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [RegularExpression(@"\d*")]
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

public enum PathType
{
    Path
}
public enum UnitType
{
    MB, GB, TB, Files, Percentage
}
public enum ThresholdType
{
    Upper, Lower
}
```

Parse function:

```
    private static StorageConfigurationModel BindToModel(int id, string pathType, string threshold, string valueType, string location, int limit)
    {
        return new StorageConfigurationModel
        {
            QueueMonitorConfigurationsID = id,
            QueueMonitorConfigTypeName = (PathType)Enum.Parse(typeof(PathType), pathType),
            Location = Convert.ToString(location.Trim()),
            Value = Convert.ToInt32(limit),
            QueueMonitorValueTypeName = (UnitType)Enum.Parse(typeof(UnitType), valueType),
            Threshold = (ThresholdType)Enum.Parse(typeof(ThresholdType), threshold)
        };
    }
```

So when I put all the data in my view and click add, nothing is triggered.

With this I call the function that calls the modelbinder:

```
        $.post('@Url.Action("AddUpdateConfigs")',
            {id: @Model.QueueMonitorConfigurationsID , pathType: $('#ddlConfigTypeName').val(), threshold:$('#ddlThreshold').val(), valueType:$('#ddlValueTypeName').val(), location: $('#txtbLocation').val(), limit: $('#txtbLimit').val(), config: $('#NewOrUpdate').val() },
            function(data){
                if (!data.Success){
                    alert(data.Description);
                }
                else{
                    //$('#gridView').load('/Storage/gvConfigurations');
                    $.get('@Url.Action("gvConfigurations", "Storage")',null,function(data){$('#gridView').html(data);},'html');
                }
            },'json');
```

Comment: It think MVC handle that automatically if Value is of type int.

Comment: Do you want to do this check client-side or server-side?

Comment: A good start : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256141(VS.98).aspx

Comment: I prefer a client side solution

Comment: checkout Knockout and Knockout-Validation if you are able to implement this at this stage of project. Make it easy to do ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On your model, add this attribute to the top of `Value`:

```
[RegularExpression(@"(\d+)")]
```

and MVC will set it invalid server-side before it gets back to the controller in the `POST` -you can then easily handle it properly.

Now, if you're set on using it in JavaScript, then use this method:

```
function isNumber(n) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
```

and then you can run that in the `onkeydown` event like this:

```
onkeydown="return isNumber(this.value);"
```

#### EDIT

To get an error message in there you **should** be able to do something like this:

```
[RegularExpression(@"(\d+)", ErrorMessage="Please enter numeric values only.")]
```

Comment: I'm not parsing the data that the user puts into a Model so this is not valid for me.

Comment: @AnnArbor87, have a look at my edit. And what are you doing with the data? If you're not `POST`ing the data back into the model, what are you doing?

Comment: The Regular expresion gives me an error saying:"Unrecognized escape sequence". I was posting the data and making a query. Now I changed and I'm parsing it to use this mvc features.
So what is better? validation with the model or JS?

Comment: @AnnArbor87, validation with the model is better because it can't get past the server-side validation, and please see my edit for the issue you saw with the `RegularExpression`. Client-side validation is a **nicety** that makes the application look prettier and prevents the post back.

Comment: When you enable unobtrusive clientside validation, the input will also be validated against the RegEx on the clientside.

Comment: @CodeCaster I already have it enabled, and it is not working.

Comment: Well I think partially works; when I put a string in a textboxfor for an int, it wont fire do the ajax post, but no message is shown near the textboxfor, how can I put a message like "input should be int"?

Comment: @AnnArbor87, I'm not sure what's happening now because I know the attribute is configured right per this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd901590(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: @AnnArbor87 put a `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(cModel => cModel.Value)` and try to read up on stuff so you understand what you are doing. :-)

Comment: I'm debugging with IE tools and seems like when I do the click on the `Apply` button, it makes the ajax post to `AddUpdateConfigs` but it gives a '500' result which means is not success

Comment: @annarbor87, then there is likely an exception happening server-side. Put a breakpoint in that API entry point and see.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud I already did and is not even reaching the first line of that Action, and is because the field `limit` that that Action receives is an int and I am sending a string.
But why the validation is not happening?

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud, @CodeCaster; do I need to have a form in order to get validation?

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use a ViewModel class that match with your user interface elements, instead of use directly your Model class to pass the info to the post action.

For instance:

```
public class StorageConfigurationViewModel
{
[Required()]
public int pathType {get;set;}
[Required()]
public int threshold {get;set;}
[Required()]
public int valueType {get;set;}
[Required()]
public int location {get;set;}
[Required()]
public int limit {get;set;}
[Required()]
public int config {get;set;}
}
```